# Get favorite beers from listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have the following problem. I am making a app called BeerApp. The problem i have now is very frustratening.

I want to get all the information of a listbox to save my favorite selected beers. The question is how can i get the information like brand, name and beertype from my listbox. The listbox only contains the brand and name. But i also need to store the beertype in my db.

The class named beer looks like this:

```
 public string name { get; private set; }
    public string brand { get; private set; }
    public int dato { get; private set; }
    public int beertype { get; private set; }

    public Beer(string pName, string pBrand, int pDato, int pBeertype)
    {
        name = pName;
        brand = pBrand;
        dato = pDato;
        beertype = pBeertype;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string myString = name + "\t\t" + brand;
        return myString; 
    }
```

Here i fill the listbox with items.

```
private void fillListbox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    addListBox.Items.Clear();
    dbbeer.DatabaseConnect();
    List < Beer > beers = dbbeer.ReadBeers();
    if (beers != null)
         {
         foreach (Beer beer in beers)
            {
                addListBox.Items.Add(beer);
            }
       }
         dbbeer.DatabaseDisconnect();
   }
```

A screenshot of the application:
[Open to see the screenshot of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfHyK.png)

Left u see the listbox i fill with beers. Right place is the place i want to get information from the left listbox.

Comment: `var selectedBeer = addListBox.SelectedItem as Beer`

Comment: Nice! U are a hero. Now i can go further with my app. Thank u